# Tic-Tac-Toe Game Error - "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python

I'm still a beginner. Currently, I am working on making a tic-tac-toe game using Python 3. One of my functions that's supposed to check whether a space is full or not keeps giving me the error message:

> "IndexError: list index out of range",

I have no idea on how to solve it. Apparently, it's the if-statement that's giving me trouble but I don't see an issue. I've already scourged the internet looking for a solution but have not found one yet. It would really be appreciated if someone could help me solve this problem.

```py
def space_check(board, position):

    space_full = False

    if board[position] == 'X' or board[position] == 'O':
        space_full = True
        print("This space is already marked.")
    else:
        print("This space is available.")
```

Comment: It means your position that you are using as an index for your board array is trying to access values that don't exist.

Comment: It is not a *dumb* question. We just can't help much with the information you have given. Read about how to provide a [mre]. It really depends on what is `board` and what is the `position`... You should debug your program by adding some prints (or even better using a debugger) and finding the problematic values

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `position` is a number that is too high and the `board` list doesn't have a value at that index.

Try printing position in the function and then comparing it to the size of the board to see where the error lies.

Remember lists are zero-indexed, so if it is `3x3`, then the highest index would be `2`, not `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a shopping list with "grapes, carrots, bread" in it and you ask what is the 4th thing in that list it doesn't make sense right? That's what this error is. You likely need to remember that the first part of the list is index 0 but length show what you would consider to be its length as in:

```
x = ['a', 'b']
```

a is x[0] and b is x[1]. However:

```
len(x) = 2
```

What you lickely need to do to fix this is to change

```
board[position]
```

to:

```
board[position-1]
```